# Best way to organize google cloud VMs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am currently developing many wordpress websites and I'm starting to use Google Cloud to host my websites.
I've thought of a way to organize my websites, however I would like to know from the community if there is a way to improve it or maybe rearrange everything (I'm still in the beginning of the project so starting from scratch is an option).

The way that I'm organizing is I create a project for each kind of website that I create (e-commerce, institutional websites...) and in each project I create the Virtual Machines that host each website.

Here is and exemple of how I'm doing it :

Folder: Copany name

```
    Project 1: E-commerce
       website 1, website 2, website 3...

    Project 2: Institutional
       website 1, website 2, website 3...
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [Creating and managing projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects): "Google Cloud projects form the basis for creating, enabling, and using all Google Cloud services including managing APIs, enabling billing, adding and removing collaborators, and managing permissions for Google Cloud resources". As a result, you can organize your resources by using project on any of the similar characteristics listed above. If your schema works for you there's no reason to change it. What do you want to improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [Google Cloud overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview) section [Projects](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview#projects):

> Any Google Cloud resources that you allocate and use must belong to a
> project. **You can think of a project as the organizing entity for what
> you're building.** A project is made up of the settings, permissions,
> and other metadata that describe your applications. **Resources within a
> single project can work together easily, for example by communicating
> through an internal network, subject to the regions-and-zones rules**.

and at the documentation [Creating and managing projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects):

> Google Cloud **projects form the basis for creating, enabling, and using
> all Google Cloud services including managing APIs, enabling billing,
> adding and removing collaborators, and managing permissions** for Google
> Cloud resources.

As a result, you can organize your resources by using project on any of the similar characteristics listed above like billing, permissions, collaborators and so on.

In addition, have a look at the article [Best practices for enterprise organizations](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations).